# Delayed onClick response React App (works on the second click but not the first)

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios, use-state

So, I have an onClick attached to a button that I want to call the tenDrinks function. On the first click, I am returned an empty array. On the second click, I am receiving exactly what I want from my axios call.
Does anyone have a clear reasoning as to why? and an explanation of what I may have to do to fix this?

A picture of the page with console logs can be found at the bottom for visualization.

````
import axios from 'axios';

const Home = () => {
  const [randomDrinks, setRandomDrinks] = useState([]);

  const tenDrinks = async () => {
    const config = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://the-cocktail-db.p.rapidapi.com/randomselection.php',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'x-rapidapi-host': 'the-cocktail-db.p.rapidapi.com',
        'x-rapidapi-key': 'ff61de8c3fmshdbbdcfd2003501ep1d77b7jsn0bc9bc4a1b9b',
        useQueryString: true,
      },
    };

    await axios(config)
      .then((res) => setRandomDrinks(res.data.drinks))
      .then((res) => console.log(randomDrinks))
      // .then((random) => console.log(randomDrinks))
      .catch(console.error);

    const eachDrink = randomDrinks.map((drink) => (
      <div key={drink.idDrink}>{drink.strDrink}</div>
    ));
    console.log(randomDrinks[0]);
    return (
      <div className='randomDrink'>
        <h3>{eachDrink}</h3>
      </div>
    );
  };
  // tenDrinks();
  const onClick = () => {
    tenDrinks();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Get 10 random cocktails</button>
      {/* <RandomDrinks /> */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2ZJ3.png
````

Comment: What is your first return from? Looks like the code needs some help...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to return the values from the tenDrinks functions as you're setting the state on return of the api data.

Simply grabbing the value of randomDrinks in your render will update with every state change like so

```
{ randomDrinks.map((drink) => (
        <div key={drink.idDrink}>{drink.strDrink}</div>
    )) 
}
```

With your complete code looking something like this

```
const Home = () => {
    const [randomDrinks, setRandomDrinks] = useState([]);

    const tenDrinks = async () => {
      const config = {
         ...
      } ;

      await axios(config)
        .then((res) => setRandomDrinks(res.data.drinks)) // This updates the value of randomDrinks
        .catch(console.error); 
    };

    const onClick = () => {
      tenDrinks();
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={onClick}>Get 10 random cocktails</button>
        {/** This will always rendered the current state value of randomDrinks */}
        { randomDrinks.map((drink) => (
            <div key={drink.idDrink}>{drink.strDrink}</div>
        )) }
      </div>
    );
};
```